# Is it possible to sign into Chrome Browser from a users OS authentication?

Tags: windows, active-directory, mac-osx, single-sign-on, google-chrome

I am curious if it would be possible to sign users into their Chrome Browsers on Windows and/or Mac automatically when they sign in to their AD account.

Our G Suite account syncs all data from our AD and we use SSO for Google so the information is there somewhere.

We push a lot of settings and apps to our users Chrome browsers when they sign in.

This is what I want to do but in the background

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en